# how to use command to download a folder from linux to local

Tags: linux, download

I want to download a folder from remote to local, by using linux command.
And I need to allocate the local directory

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
scp -r user@remotehost:remotepath localpath
```

for example

```
scp -r bob@mybox.com:projects/foo .
```